# generating a MouseEvent in JavaFX

Tags: events, mouse, javafx-2

I'm in need of simulating a `MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED`. I want to use the **fireEvent** method of a particular **Node** in order to dispatch an event of the aforementioned type. However, I am struggling with generating one. It appears that **javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent** has no valid constructor, but old `java.awt.event.MouseEvent` objects can be instantiated this way. Still, I haven't found any working solution for conversion. How do I go around this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can simulate mouse click using `java.awt.Robot.mouse*` methods

Comment: right, but how do I convert `java.awt.event.MouseEvent` to `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent`? The method signature that handles the actual event requires the **MouseEvent** from javafx.* package

Comment: if you are using Robot class it will simulate mouse click, which Java FX infrastructure will catch and create all required classes by itself. You just say smth like `Robot.mousePress(10,10)` for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can generate a MouseEvent using the deprecated MouseEvent.impl_mouseEvent API.  I did this previously in this [forum thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2302889) for JavaFX 2.0.  Note that the API is deprecated for a reason - it is private API used in the implementation of JavaFX and the API is not guaranteed to maintain the same signature or even exist in future versions (which can be evidenced because the original code I posted in the forum thread no longer compiles.

The correct solution to generating such an event is to have a public API so support this.  There has already been a request filed to supply this functionality [RT-9383 "Add proper constructors & factory methods to event classes, remove impl"](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-9383).  This jira is scheduled to be completed next year for JavaFX 3.0.

In the meantime, usage of the Robot class as Sergey suggests is probably your best method.

---

*Update:* Java 8 added [public constructors for javafx.event.MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#MouseEvent-javafx.event.EventType-double-double-double-double-javafx.scene.input.MouseButton-int-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-javafx.scene.input.PickResult-) and the (as indicated in Jay Thakkar's answer), you can fire such an event using [Event.fireEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#fireEvent-javafx.event.EventTarget-javafx.event.Event-) (you can also [fire events on Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#fireEvent-javafx.event.Event-)).

Comment: Quite an elaborate answer. Thank you.

Comment: Jira access works for me.  The new event constructors have been added to the [Java 8 branch](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) to be released next year.

Answer (score 17):

This will fire a single primary mouse click at your node:

```
import javafx.event.Event; 
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton; 
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

Event.fireEvent(YOUR NODE, new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 0,
                0, 0, 0, MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1, true, true, true, true,
                true, true, true, true, true, true, null));
```

Comment: Packages for reference:    
    import javafx.event.Event;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

Comment: Why do you pass `true` for all of the modifier keys (`shiftDown`, `controlDown`, etc.)? I was under the assumption that a plain jane click wouldn't have any of the modifiers down.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use a simple "hack" to do a programmatic click on the button.
Create this method in a "Util" class:

```
public static void click(javafx.scene.control.Control control) {
    java.awt.Point originalLocation = java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    javafx.geometry.Point2D buttonLocation = control.localToScreen(control.getLayoutBounds().getMinX(), control.getLayoutBounds().getMinY());
    try {
        java.awt.Robot robot = new java.awt.Robot();
        robot.mouseMove((int)buttonLocation.getX(), (int)buttonLocation.getY());
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseMove((int) originalLocation.getX(), (int)originalLocation.getY());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then, to "click" on the button just call the method click passing your button as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a handler, it sets a public property. You can get the event from that property and call handle():

```
button1.setOnMouseClicked()....
the corresponding property is
button1.onMouseClickedProperty().get().handle(me);//where me is some MouseEvent object
```