# Embedding JavaScript/HTML in AnyLogic application

Tags: user-interface, javafx, javafx-8, anylogic

I'm developing a Java program in AnyLogic that requires a complex, dynamic interface. This is painfully tedious and downright unmaintainable in Java, but -- given its wide array of UI-related libraries -- should be relatively simple to implement in JavaScript. I'm therefore trying to embed a web view into my Java application using JavaFX's `WebBrowser`, and `WebEngine`. [I can load a website as per this tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) However, when I click in the window nothing is responsive: no links work, the scrollbar doesn't respond, and menu items fail to respond. Am I missing something? Is there a way to inject a click manually into the web page? (Is embedding a web browser even a sensible way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?)

Comment: Should just work.  Please provide a link to the website which is not working for you or you can provide an mcve if you cannot provide a link.

Comment: I am working on similar principle, I use FXML+CSS+JavaScript combo to achieve flexibility. You can load them from a web server.

Comment: @jewelsea that's good to know: the environment that I'm embedding the control into -- AnyLogic -- must be causing my problem. I am using a system that wraps its Swing/JavaFX controls in custom classes, and so my issue must be the translation of clicks from the custom classes (even though I'm handling the clicks!) to the JavaFX component. I'll keep pursuing this thanks to your input and update the question / answer as I can. In the meantime, do you know how to pass a mouse click to the WebEngine/Browser? It could help me narrow down the possible problems I'm having.

Comment: There is nothing to pass.  WebView will handle clicks automatically.

Comment: In the unlikely event that you really need to generate mouse events, see: [generating a mouse event in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552176/generating-a-mouseevent-in-javafx)

Comment: I came across that and tried it a few days ago. I'm confident now that it's an issue with the way AnyLogic embeds controls, and I've contacted them about it. We'll see what happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was tool-specific: the environment I use (AnyLogic v7.x) uses an embedded JPanel to draw shapes that the user does not normally directly access. While shapes can be added to the environment successfully as a shape, they don't receive normal input (e.g., mouse input) unless added to the JPanel instead. (Adding them in this way brings its own complications like managing zooms and  translations manually, but that's beyond the scope of the question.)